# textbox value being lost on button submit?

Tags: asp.net

I have a form with a text box on it:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"Text="Email address" onclick="this.value='';"></asp:TextBox>
```

When I submit the form with this text box and try to get txtEmail.Text to send the inputted form values somewhere I always get "Email address" as the submitted value, it should be the input that was entered into the field, am I doing this right?

```
protected void btnSendMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Response.Write(txtEmail.Text); // just a test
}
```

Comment: Maybe you also set the default value somewhere in your code-behind. Check the constructor of the page and the events that were handled before, e.g. Page_Load()...

Comment: There must be some other code that is causing the problem as your code above works fine for me.

Comment: Alright, I'll skim over it as well, i figure this is such a trivial thing but this is driving me crazy. Be back shortly.

Comment: Why is the Textbox Tag improperly formatted? `runat="server"Text="Email address"` does not work but `runat="server" Text="Email address"` does.

Comment: Doh! fixed it, I was resetting the form on postback, my bad.